# Double log statements

Tags: cakephp, ubuntu-12.04

I have weird issue, it might be something silly but I can't find where the problem is.
I develop an application on cakephp 2.x and when I log data from the controller it appears twice in the log. Something like this:

- 2013-05-24 11:50:19 Debug: excel file uploaded
- 2013-05-24 11:50:19 Debug: excel file uploaded
- 2013-05-24 11:50:19 Debug: fire test
- 2013-05-24 11:50:19 Debug: fire test

Just to add some fun, it doesn't happen in all functions in that controller, only in two out of six. It annoys me a lot and I don't see what way I should to dig to get rid of it.
Any ideas?

EDIT:
OK, I found that this happens when I log to the two different files in one method.
When I change the line: CakeLog::write('time'....);  to CakeLog::write('debug'....);
everything works fine. Like in the following method:

```
function file_upload() {
    if (!$this->request->data) {           
    } else {
        CakeLog::write('time', 'start working at: ' . date('m/d/Y', strtotime("now")));

        $data = Sanitize::clean($this->request->data);

        CakeLog::write('debug', 'test statement');

        if ($data['Scrap']['excel_submittedfile']['type'] === 'application/vnd.ms-excel' && $data['Scrap']['csv_submittedfile']['type'] === 'text/csv') {
            $tmp_xls_file = $data['Scrap']['excel_submittedfile']['tmp_name'];
            $xls_file = $data['Scrap']['excel_submittedfile']['name'];
            $tmp_csv_file = $data['Scrap']['csv_submittedfile']['tmp_name'];
            $csv_file = $data['Scrap']['csv_submittedfile']['name'];
            $upload_dir = WWW_ROOT . "/files/";
            if (file_exists($upload_dir) && is_writable($upload_dir)) {
                if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_xls_file, $upload_dir . $xls_file) && move_uploaded_file($tmp_csv_file, $upload_dir . $csv_file)) {

                    CakeLog::write('debug', 'excel file uploaded');

                    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'edit', $xls_file, $csv_file));
                } else {
                    echo 'upload failed';
                }
            } else {
                echo 'Upload directory is not writable, or does not exist.';
            }
        } else {
            echo 'make sure the files are in correct format';
        }
    }
}
```

I guess it has something to do  with declarations of log files in bootstrap.php. So it's not that big problem just annoying.

Comment: You sure you're not somehow calling the method twice?  We can't help you without some code.

Comment: I'm sure there is no second call to the method because it runs for quite a while but(in terms of minutes) but the double statements match each other up to the seconds and it happens for all log statements in that method.

Comment: We can't help you without some code.  Paste a [basic example](http://sscce.org/) into your question.

Comment: Yeah, I'm having the same issue... Using the default log configuration.  Calling either `CakeLog::write('debug', 'aaa')` or `$this->log('bbb', 'debug')` results in double-entries in the logs... Weird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because your call

```php
CakeLog::write('time', 'start working at: ' . date('m/d/Y', strtotime("now")));
```

Will attempt to write a log of the type: "time". Since there is no stream configured to handle that the CakeLog will create a "default" stream for you to handle this log call.

The problem is that, from now on you will have a "default" stream configured that will catch all logs and double them for debug and error logs.

The solution is to properly configure the log in the bootstrap.php file like this:

```php
CakeLog::config('time_stream', array(
    'engine' => 'FileLog',
    'types' => array( 'time' ), //<--here is the log type of 'time'
    'file' => 'time', //<-- this will go to time.log
) );
```

Of course, that if you use other log types you will need to configure streams for those as well, otherwise the default catch-all stream will be configured for you and you will be having the same problem again.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. Configuring the bootstrap.php definitely solved the problem. Actually,not using debug.log with other log files in the same method helps too. Like, using aaa.log and bbb.log in the same method doesn't create any problem of doubling.